# when retrieving data from firebase database the browser shows undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to retrieve data from firebase database. The returned data shows like

`undefined undefined undefined`

**the code I used is**

```js
var query = firebase.database().ref().child("users/-Ly-dBv9xSiBf-UO0A8Q").orderByKey();
query.once("value") .then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

      var key = childSnapshot.key;

      var childData = childSnapshot.val().messageText;
 document.writeln(childData);

  });
});
```

[image: database reference]

Comment: I don't know firebase very well (as opposed to firestore), but doesn't that path on the `child()` method indicate a single document?  If so, would the returned snapshot be treated as an array (forEach)? or as a single doc?  If the latter, then you'd use `val()` right away, skipping forEach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows `undefined` because first, the reference is at the random ID node therefore you don't have to loop. Second, you don't have an attribute called `messageText` in your database. Your code should be like this:

```
var query = firebase.database().ref().child("users/-Ly-dBv9xSiBf-UO0A8Q").orderByKey();
query.once("value") .then(function(snapshot) {
      var childData = snapshot.val().password;
      var userId = snapshot.val().user_id;
 document.writeln(childData);
});
```

Comment: i would like to retrieve the **user_id** with the child **password** what changes should i make in the code?